# php code or api to fetch all product categories from amazon

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get all categories from Amazon. Couldn't find any specific Api to fetch Product Categories for a marketplace.Please help me to get all product Categories.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far ?

Comment: you can give some more information about your question to get some answers.Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have to push products from project in php platform to amazon..For that i have to get all the categories available in amazon. I have been looking http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetProductCategoriesForASIN.html  but its not there

Answer (score 0):

I Found the categories associated with the seller account.Login to the amazon seller account:https://sellercentral.amazon.in/  then in Inventory->Add Product Via Upload->Download Template->Browse Tree Guide .Browse Tree Guide is an xls file containing the category,subcategory and node information.